# Prove $\{f_n\}$ converge to $X^*$ iff $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent to closure of $B(0,1)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ a normed vectorial space. Let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence in $X^*$

Prove  $\{f_n\}$ converge to $X^*$ iff $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent to closure of $B(0,1)$

Note: $X^*$ is the topologic dual

**My attempt:**
$\implies$ Suppose $\{f_n\}$ converge to $X^*$

Then for $\epsilon>0$ exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq N$ then $||fn-f||_{\infty}<\epsilon$

Note

$$||fn-f||_{\infty}=\sup_{||x||=1}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon\implies|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

This happen $\forall x\in X$ in particular for all$x\in B(0,1)$

Moreover, $f$ is bounded and $B(0,1)$ is bounded.

Here i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by $\{f_n\}$ converges to $X^*$?

Comment: I believe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535369/strong-topology-and-uniform-convergence/3535433#3535433) is what you are asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Textbook with proof that product of two Gaussian functions is also Gaussian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/textbook-with-proof-that-product-of-two-gaussian-functions-is-also-gaussian)